# GetFromLocation method

Tags: android, gps

Why if I take the andress with this code `List<Address> loc = getFromLocation(lat,long,1);` the address is correct but the civic number is wrong because if I put the latitude e longitude into Sygic it give me another civic number.

Example :

- Via Merulana 19,Roma (with `getFromLocation`)
- Via merulana 15/16,Roma
  (with sygic when I put the longitude and latitude)

Answer (score 1):

Because they are different services. `getFromLocation` uses the reverse geocoding provided by Google, as for Sygic, they probably use their own service. Reverse geocoding isn't expected to have that degree of accuracy (ie match the exact house number).

Comment: Is not that easy. First, how do you know that the user gps location is accurate? There is always some degree of error. You can't depend on an accurate fix of the gps and/or an accurate reverse geocoding. What I would do is to record the gps location, do a reverse geocoding and present the user the results. The user then chooses if he want to submit that address or correct it before sending it.